# Sql server 2012 management studio is not showing me the Databasemail

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

I am trying to send mail through SQL server. But in my case when i expanded the SQL Server Logs i cannot find my Database mail. How can i do this Please help me guys.
I tried so many ways for showing the database mail there.. i could get anything. Please help me guys.

I tried the following codes too

```
// To fix the run the following script:

 USE Master
GO
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
reconfigure with override
GO
sp_configure 'Database Mail XPs', 1
GO
reconfigure 
GO
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0
GO
```

**Please find the below link to my snapshot of the SQL server 2012 management studio. I dont have Database mail there..**

https://imageshack.com/i/f0xY6qH2p

Answer (score 1):

Express edition of SQL Server does not have Database Mail feature.

Use Standard, Web, Workgroup, Enterprise or Datacenter edition.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.105%29.ASPX

See also this article, it can eventually help you:

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/07/01/60245.aspx

Comment: what file i should take..   Please choose a file type:

 Azure
 ISO
 CAB

Comment: You would have to copy files from installed instance of SQL Server 2012 (or your version) Standard  and copy them to your Express edition. Probably it will not enable the feature in Management Studio, but I have never tried it. It is a hack, so it may or may not work.